# How to draw a rectangle in a html file dynamically using javascript ? Google chrome extension Page Ruler have similar feature

Tags: javascript, shapes

I want to draw rectangles over texts or paragraphs in a HTML file. I want to achieve this using javascript without the use of canvas. Multiple rectangles can also exist for selecting multiple paragraphs. Is there any library for achieving this kind of functionality.

[Click here to see the intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVQOA.png)

page Ruler link here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler-redux/giejhjebcalaheckengmchjekofhhmal?hl=en-US

Comment: Are these rectangles for UI purposes only. Can you just use `border: 1px solid` on the container of these texts or paragraphs

Comment: i have to get the position of the rectangles corners as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here at StackOverflow, we help solve your problems, not do the work for you. You have to attempt doing this, and if you encounter any problems, we will be glad to help you. Please read through HTML/javascript tutorials and try to find out how this can be doneز

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the absolute positioned `div` element to draw a rectangle over the web page. You need to listen for events when the user presses the mouse button (`mousedown`), when the user moves the mouse (`mousemove`), and when the user releases the button (`mouseup`). Here is a simple example:

```
const rectangle = document.createElement("div");
rectangle.style.position = "absolute";
rectangle.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(204,230,255, 0.7)";
rectangle.style.border = "1px dashed black";
document.body.appendChild(rectangle);

    let isDragged = false;
    let rectangleCoords = [];

    const clearRectangleCoords = () => {
        rectangleCoords = [];
    };

    const addFirstRectangleCoords = coords => {
        rectangleCoords[0] = coords;
    };

    const addSecondRectangleCoords = coords => {
        rectangleCoords[1] = coords;
    };

    const redrawRectangle = () => {
        const top = Math.min(rectangleCoords[0].y, rectangleCoords[1].y);
        const height = Math.max(rectangleCoords[0].y, rectangleCoords[1].y) - top;
        const left = Math.min(rectangleCoords[0].x, rectangleCoords[1].x);
        const width = Math.max(rectangleCoords[0].x, rectangleCoords[1].x) - left;
      rectangle.style.top = top + "px";
      rectangle.style.height = height + "px";
      rectangle.style.left = left + "px";
      rectangle.style.width = width + "px";
    };

    window.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
        isDragged = true;
      clearRectangleCoords();
      addFirstRectangleCoords({x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY});
      addSecondRectangleCoords({x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY});
      redrawRectangle();
    });

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
        if (isDragged) {
        addSecondRectangleCoords({x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY});
        redrawRectangle();
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
        if (isDragged) {
        addSecondRectangleCoords({x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY});
        redrawRectangle();
            isDragged = false;
      }
    });
```

You can play with the code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/artk7b4g/)

Comment: This is great for one rectangle. If i wanted to draw next rectangle after drawing the previous one, what changes shall i make??

Comment: I make some changes to allow drawing more rectangles. You can delete the rectangle using right-click. https://jsfiddle.net/wq6nyejm/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight pure `p` elements, you can manipulate the backgroundColor property of the paragraphs, but you'd have to make sure they're displayed `inline-block`.

```js
document.getElementById('bttn').addEventListener('click', highlight);    
function highlight() {
    var p = document.getElementById('target'); 
    p.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000'; //change background color
}
```

```html
<!--make sure the paragraph is displayed inline-block, or else the entire line  will be highlighted. -->

<p id="target" style="display:inline-block">This is a paragraph.</p>  
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button id="bttn">Click here to highlight</button>
```